# Error while building OpenCV 3.1.0 with extra modules on OS X Mavericks

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I am a beginner in OpenCV, using OpenCV 3.1.0 (downloaded from OpenCV.org) with Mac OS X 10.9.5.

I was trying to run a [code](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html) which needs **contrib.hpp**, then I found [the extra modules from Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). There is a command from the page:

```
$ cd <opencv_build_directory>
$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>
$ make -j5
```

Everything was successful before I did **make**, it shows an error of **no matching function for call to 'calibrateCamera'** :

```
[ 92%] Building CXX object modules/aruco/CMakeFiles/opencv_aruco.dir/src/aruco.cpp.o
/Users/Youko/downloads/opencv_contrib-master/modules/aruco/src/aruco.cpp:1583:12: error: 
      no matching function for call to 'calibrateCamera'
    return calibrateCamera(processedObjectPoints, processedImagePoints, ...
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Youko/downloads/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d/include/opencv2/calib3d.hpp:844:21: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires at most 9 arguments, but 12 were
      provided
CV_EXPORTS_W double calibrateCamera( InputArrayOfArrays objectPoints,
                    ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/aruco/CMakeFiles/opencv_aruco.dir/src/aruco.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/aruco/CMakeFiles/opencv_aruco.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

In the case of I wanna keep the version of Mac OSX, I was thinking of change the version of OpenCV, so I've downloaded OpenCV from Github, and tried to install the OpenCV with following command (it was the same way as how I've installed OpenCV 3.1.0 successfully):

```
$ cd <opencv_source_directory>
$ mkdir release
$ cd release
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

But there is another problem when I tried **make**:

```
[ 44%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_mjpeg_decoder.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_avfoundation_mac.mm.o
[ 44%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.dylib
ld: framework not found CoreImage
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.3.1.0.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I thought maybe there was something wrong with **cmake**, so I tried the following command as well but the same error occurred with **make**:

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

I've googled for the problem and it seems like I must need the **QuartzCore**, but most of people said it should be included in the Xcode (I am using Xcode 6.2 btw). I tried both ways to figure it out but I still have no idea why I can't build the extra modules. (I think the most weird problem is that I cannot install OpenCV cloned from Github, but I just wanna show I tried this way but it wasn't successful FYI.)

I'd be most grateful for any help and suggestions!